# CW-structure on $CX$ with only one $0$-cell?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a path-connected CW-complex, with a CW-structure with one $0$-cell.

We define the cone on $X$ to be the space

$$CX:= (X \times I) /(X \times \{1\}).$$

If we equip the interval $I$ with the usual CW-structure with two $0$-cells and one $1$-cell, then the CW-structure which is induced on $CX$ has two $0$-cells. One corresponds to the unique $0$-cell in $X$, and one corresponds to the factored-out $X \times \{1\}$. $X$ embeds as a CW-complex into $CX$.

Is it possible to construct the cone on $X$ in such a way that it can be equipped with a CW-structure with only one $0$-cell, and such that $X \hookrightarrow CX$ is still an inclusion of $CW$-complexes? Or, is there an alternative way of embedding $X$ - as a CW-complex - into a contractible space $CX$ which has only one zero cell (this contractible space not having to be homeomorphic to the cone)? A sort of homotopy theoretic analogue to the above construction, but with this alternative CW-structure?

This is possible in the case of $X = S^1$, for example. We can equip $CX = D^2$ with a structure where we have "squashed together" the two $0$-cells which would arise after constructing the cone on $S^1$ in the above way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! This can be gratuitously called a model for the 0th Postnikov approximation of $X$.

Start with $X$ and inductively attach cells to kill all the homotopy groups, similarly as to how you would create an Eilenberg-Maclane space. After you have killed all the homotopy groups, we have a CW complex with trivial homotopy groups. By Whitehead, this is contractible. By construction, X is a subcomplex. Clearly we have not added any 0-cells.

An interesting question is whether you can make this functorial without changing the requirement on 0-cells.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: To check my sanity, am I right in saying that "killing homotopy groups" here in the way you suggest is akin to inductively taking representatives of non-trivial homotopy classes, and attaching disks of the appropriate dimension using those representatives as the attaching map?

Comment: @Matt Yep, by cellular approximation you can do this without affecting lower homotopy groups, and by a more careful argument the effect on the homotopy group you are trying to kill is to quotient by the smallest subgroup containing that element that is closed under the action of the fundamental group. For example, in the fundamental group the effect is to quotient out by the normal subgroup generated by that element.

Comment: And the reason I mentioned the term "Postnikov approximation" is that these things occur for all n and have models like above, but where I just start killing homotopy groups above degree n. But just like the cone, these have different models. These things are related to universal covers (and the higher homotopical generalizations). For example, the homotopy fiber of the inclusion into the first Postnikov approximation is the universal cover.